# origin/HEAD vs origin/master

Tags: git

I initially had two branches in bitbucket - master and feature (+4/-2 commits as compared to master).

In process of deleting the feature branch - I have messed up with the origin/HEAD. Now my master is changed to HEAD and the feature branch is changed to the default branch master.

Please provide insights and suggestions to fix this.

| Before | Current | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| master | HEAD | master |
| feature | master | (delete branch) |

```
$ git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
```

Comment: please try git reflog (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) followed by reset --hard to your branch hash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`origin/HEAD` represents the default branch on the remote. `origin` - is just alias to remote url. And `master` - is just name. Git does not have some special meaning of `master`. So your `feature` branch can't become `master`, actually - that does not make sense. But it could be merged into `master` - which is apparently your case.

`origin/HEAD -> origin/master` means, that your default remote branch is `master` branch. And based on the output of `git branch -r` it is seen, that on remote server you have only `master`, no `feature` anymore.

So if you merged `feature` into `master`, deleted `feature`, and `git branch -r` gives you the output which you posted - seems that everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks @kosist, this makes sense! I have two branches on remote - refs/heads/HEAD and refs/heads/master. How do I remove refs/heads/HEAD?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some additional background information to supplement [kosist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73183811/1256452) (q.v.):

- `HEAD`, in any Git repository, is a very special name.  It is normally a *symbolic reference*, which in effect means that it contains some other branch's name.  This gets a bit more complicated on server Git repositories than on clients, but the general idea here is the same regardless of server vs client.
- When you run `git clone`, you make a *new repository* by cloning some existing repository.  By default, this new repository copies *all the commits* from the original repository, and *none of the branch names*.

Of course, the new repository is a Git repository.  This means it has a special name, `HEAD`, that is normally a symbolic reference.  This is *your* Git repository's `HEAD`, and in your repository, you will create new branch names and switch to them, e.g.:

```
git switch -c newbranch
```

At this point *your* `HEAD` refers to your new branch `newbranch`.

The repository you cloned, which *your* Git repository calls `origin`, still has all of its original branch names.  It presumably still has the same branch as *its* current branch, so that *its* `HEAD` still refers to *its* `main` or `master` or whatever.

We now get into one of the complications.  A *server* repository is normally a "bare" repository, i.e., one with no working tree.  We use `git switch` or `git checkout` to update the working tree in our (client) Git repository, and this changes which *branch* the name `HEAD` remembers, in our (client) Git repository.  If you could log in to GitHub, or wherever the server may be, and `cd path/to/repo.git` and `git switch somebranch` there, that would change the branch name stored in the *server*'s Git-repository-`HEAD`—but if that server has only *bare* clones, the `git switch` and `git checkout` commands don't work in those clones.<sup>1</sup>

Nonetheless, most service providers (e.g., GitHub) provide some way to change the branch name stored *in* that service provider's repositories.  On GitHub, you do this with their web interface, using their "set default branch name" pages.  (You can also use [the `gh` cli](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh), if you install that.)  The only reason to do this is that when users run:

```
git clone <url>
```

the *new branch* they get in their new clone is a *copy* of the default branch.  However, if they write:

```
git clone -b develop <url>
```

the *new branch* they get in their new clone is `develop` (a copy of the `develop` branch in the server's clone).

So, in short (if it's not too late), the point of setting `HEAD` in a *server* repository is to set the *default branch that people running `git clone` from some client* will get.  And that's all it's good for ... well, *almost* all.

Now, as you probably already know and I just said, when you clone some other repository (e.g., https://github.com/git/git.git), you get *all their commits* and *none of their branches* and then your own Git software creates *one* branch—the default branch, unless you used `-b`—but that's not the **full** story.  The full story goes on to mention that each of their *branch* names becomes one of your *remote-tracking names*.  That is, because this Git-repository-for-Git has branches named `seen` and `next` for instance, you get `origin/seen` and `origin/next` in your clone.  The **really full** story then has to go on to add more conditionals here, since `--single-branch` or `--depth` can *turn off* this behavior, but we'll stop at this point and just claim this:

- All of their *branch names* become *remote-tracking names* in your clone.

So if they have a `master` or `main` (the Git repository for Git now has both), and a `seen` and a `next` for instance, you get an `origin/master` or `origin/main` and an `origin/seen` and an `origin/next`.  So here's Git's somewhat dim-bulb version of a bright idea: *They have a `HEAD`, so why not make an `origin/HEAD` too?*

That's exactly what your `origin/HEAD` is, or is supposed to be: a copy of their `HEAD`.  Their `HEAD` is a symbolic reference to their `main`, so your `origin/HEAD` is now a symbolic reference to your `origin/main`.  Or, their `HEAD` is a symbolic reference to their `ice-cream-is-tasty` branch, so your `origin/HEAD` is now a symbolic reference to your `origin/ice-cream-is-tasty` name.

Note that your `origin/*` names are not *branch* names ... well, not *exactly*.  I like to call them *remote-tracking names*.  Git officially calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, but they don't work like your own branch names.  They stick around so that your Git can remember their Git's branch names.  Your `git fetch` command will update your remote-tracking names.  Unless you run `git fetch --prune` or `git remote origin prune` or similar, though, your Git software won't delete your remote-tracking name when they delete their branch name—so that's one way they don't work right, sort of—and you can't `git switch` to one of these remote-tracking names, which is why they're not *branch* names.<sup>2</sup>

With all of this, you might expect that every time you run `git fetch origin`, your Git would find out if they've moved their `HEAD` from (say) their `main` to (say) their `develop`, and if so, your Git would make your `origin/HEAD` a symbolic reference to your `origin/develop`.  That would brighten up Git's dim bulb a bit, so therefore it doesn't actually happen.  Instead, your `origin/HEAD` gets set up *once*, when you run `git clone`, and is never touched again.

Well, that is, it isn't touched *unless* you run `git remote set-head`.  The `git remote` command has a bunch of sub-commands, and the `set-head` command is how you change your own `origin/HEAD` for your remote named `origin`.  If you'd like your `origin/HEAD` to refer to your `origin/seen`, you run `git remote set-head`, like this:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/main
  origin/maint
  origin/master
  origin/next
  origin/seen
  origin/todo
$ git remote set-head origin seen
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/seen
  origin/main
  origin/maint
  origin/master
  origin/next
  origin/seen
  origin/todo
```

If you'd like your Git to call up their Git (over at `origin`, i.e., to call up whatever Git-like software answers at the URL for the original repository) and *ask them* about their `HEAD` and update your `origin/HEAD` accordingly, you run `git remote set-head origin --auto`:

```
$ git remote set-head origin --auto
origin/HEAD set to master
```

and now I'm back to the old `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` setup.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, not without a `--work-tree` or equivalent, anyway.  This lays a *different* trap for those working with server-side bare repositories, of course.

<sup>2</sup>Note that `git switch` requires the `--detach` option when using a remote-tracking name.  The `git checkout` command doesn't require the option, it just *assumes* it.  Either way you end up in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode, which is Git's weird way of saying that you are no longer on any branch at all.  Since you aren't on a branch, when you use these names, they must not be *branch* names, even if Git calls them "remote-tracking branch names".  The word *branch* in here is just plain misleading.

---

#### Besides a lot of pointless fussing about, what good is any of this?

Some things will show `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` or whatever.  We saw above that `git branch -r` will do that, for instance.  This is, at least potentially, *stale information;* you must run `git remote set-head origin --auto` to update it.  Then `git branch -r` will only be a few seconds stale, instead of hours, days, weeks, or years stale (depending on how long ago you ran `git clone`, vs how long ago you ran `git remote set-head`).

It *is* information, stale or not, but is it any good?  **We now turn to [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is very important and which you should probably re-read every week until you're pretty familiar with the whole thing.**  It's very long and you should probably just study a paragraph or two each time.  This documentation tells you *how* `git log`, `git checkout` / `git switch`, `git branch`, `git reset`, and so many other commands use the string arguments you give them to find at least one commit.  For instance, when you run:

```
git log develop
```

how does Git know what commits to show?  The answer *starts* with this gitrevisions documentation.

In general, you can give a raw commit hash ID to most Git commands—with the important exception of `git switch` / `git checkout`, which do something different when you give them a *branch name* than they would do with a raw hash ID.  Giving Git a raw hash ID means *that commit*, so if `origin/main` means `30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8`, `git show origin/main` and `git show 30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8` do exactly the same thing.

Up near the top of this documentation page, under the **SPECIFYING REVISIONS** section, there's a six-step sequence listed this way:

> `<refname>, e.g., master, heads/master, refs/heads/master`
>       A symbolic ref name. E.g. `master` typically means the commit object referenced by `refs/heads/master`. If you happen to have both `heads/master` and `tags/master`, you can explicitly say `heads/master` to tell Git which one you mean. When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1. If ...
> 2. otherwise ...
> 3. otherwise ...
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

I've left in only steps 4 through 6 here because they're the ones we're going to encounter now:

- If you say `git show master` or `git show main`, and there's a *branch name* `master` or `main`, this matches the step 4 rule and that's the commit you see.
- If you say `git show origin/main` and there's a *remote-tracking name* `refs/remotes/origin/main`, this matches the step 5 rule and that's the commit you see.
- But if you just say `git show origin` and there's a *remote-tracking name* `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, this matches the step 6 rule, and that's the commit you see.

So the fact that there's an `origin/HEAD`—assuming you haven't *deleted* it, which you can do with `git remote set-head` as it has a `--delete` option—means that just writing `origin` where a commit hash ID is required causes your Git to find `origin/HEAD`, which is presumably a symbolic reference to the default branch over on `origin`.

**That's it.**  That's the "good thing", if you consider it a good thing.  You can use the name `origin` to mean `origin/HEAD`.  Personally, I consider this a *bad* thing because it means that if you run:

```
git push origin origin
```

it *works* and the first `origin` means *the remote named `origin`* and the second `origin` means *the commit found by looking up `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`* and **this is horribly confusing to newbies, and of virtually no use to anyone who understands what I just said** without having to plow through the Git manual pages multiple times.

(Is this a rant?  Perhaps it is: I think Git is incredibly useful and has a lot of things going for it, and at the same time, it has some really bad user interface decisions embedded in it, that make it *really hard* for people to use.  Each of these features has a reason for its existence, but taken as a whole, they're a nightmarish jumble of traps for the unwary.  That's not how software ought to be, if possible.  Still, Git is what it is; we just have to be careful how we use it, and—like C++ in so many ways—be careful which feature set we pick to use.)